# Error Java Heap size in Android Studio 1.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, heap-memory

I recently updated Android Studio from **1.2** to **1.3.1**.
After updating Gradle Sync failed message is started showing up to increase Java heap size.

Following is the screenshot of error.

TIA

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your Android Studio Folder Where it is installed. There is File `stduio.exe` and `studio64.exe` with file type of `VMOPTIONS`, open it in notepad you will see Something like this:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.3
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

According to error you may need to change 2 values in it.

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1280m
```

check this value and change it.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem again even after following your answer. It was working but again it started showing error.

Comment: have you updated your AS again with new version ? if yes then old file will be replaced with new one

Comment: NO I didn't updated. Now I tried Rustam answer and now its working.

Comment: ok, great it worked. I think it is used for only that project.

Comment: Yes only for that project

Answer (score 12):

open your projects `gradle.properties` file and paste it.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 7, what worked for me was to point the Android Studio JDK location to where the system JDK (latest) was located.

In the following images, I've marked in red the bits that should be the same.

Android Studio project, `File > Project Structure > SDK Location > JDK Location`:
[image]

Command line, `java -version`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just open the `gradle.properties` file in your projects and add:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

I met this problem when I upgraded my system to `win10`

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio go to **Help-> Edit Custom VM Options**. Hit yes button and then change 1st two values.
More Info - https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you had. But now I have solve it just Updating my JDK version 1.7 to 1.8. Now it’s working fine for me. And configure the Environment Variable with JAVA_HOME and Android Studio ->Project Structure->SDK Location=>JDK Location.