# Failed to sync Gradle project

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am using Android studio 1.3.1 and getting this failed to sync Gradle project error :

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough space for
object heap.            
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file,
sets the  maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

my default `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048` and `MaxPermSize=512m` still it is showing me this error, can anybody tell me why I am getting this error?

Comment: Please check my answer at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964072/error-java-heap-size-in-android-studio-1-3-1/31964290#31964290)

Comment: Yes,i also faced same error,you should update your android studio to 1.5.

Comment: You can find an solution over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045417/android-studio-gradle-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap)

Answer (score 9):

**Method 1 :**

For Android Studio 1.3 :

Step 1 : Open **gradle.properties** file in your Android Studio project.

Step 2 : Add this line at the end of the file

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m
```

Above methods seems to work but if in case it won't then do this

**Method 2 :**

Step 1 : Start Android studio and close any open project (**File > Close Project**).

Step 2 : On Welcome window, Go to **Configure > Settings**.

Step 3 : Go to **Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler**

Step 4 : **Change Build process heap size (Mbytes) to 1024** and **Additional build process to VM Options to -Xmx512m**.

Step 5 : Close or **Restart Android Studio**.

Comment: After a bit of research, this is the answer that made the most sense.  At it appears to have worked.  Spiffy!

Comment: May i know why this heap is used.is that for java objects or for gradle build files heap memory?

Answer (score 8):

try this way
Open `gradle.properties` file.

add this line at the end:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m
```

or

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

Answer (score 1):

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

Add this Line to the End of the `gradle.properties` file in Your project.

remember without `'#'`..

Answer (score 0):

in my case, if you use firebase with this dependency:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:21.4.2
```

it will make
Error:Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough space for
object heap

so you have to erase ktx:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.2
```