# Android Studio Build gradle OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, jvm

I'm new in Android. I import Github project in Android studio, but i see this problem `Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

> Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   .
>   Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
>   For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
>   *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m*
>   [Read Gradle's configuration guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)
> [Read about Java's heap size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

I can't fix this problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022765/failed-to-sync-gradle-project)  .
how should i do to fix that?

Comment: Maybe this can help:
    [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32133013/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-on-android-1-4)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One of the methods below should work for you:

> METHOD 1 :

Open gradle.properties file from your project tree
add this line at the memory allocation line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m
```

or

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

or

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=1024m -Xmx1024m
```

Depending on the Memory of your computer. Then

> Invalidate Caches/Restart project from the File > Invalidate Caches/Restart

To clean up your gradle cache and implement your new heap size memory changes

> METHOD 2 :

Step 1 : Start Android studio and close any open project **(File > Close Project).**

Step 2 : On Welcome window, Go to **Configure > Settings.**

Step 3 : Go to Build, Execution, **Deployment > Compiler**

Step 4 : Change Build process **heap size (Mbytes) to 512** and Additional build process to VM Options to **-Xmx512m**. *Or any memory allocation in correspondent to your PC*

Step 5 : Revalidate/Restart Android Studio.

[image]

> METHOD 3 :

Go to your Android Studio Folder Where it is installed. There is File **stduio.exe** and **studio64.exe** with file type of **VMOPTIONS**, open it in notepad you will see Something like this:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1280m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=225m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.3
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

Then change two values to suite you memory as below

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1280m
```

Comment: i added them(part 1, part 2 , part 3) . i do these steps but i have Error yet

Comment: I have updated my answer with two other methods. I am very sure the methods will work for you else i will advise you to _update your IDE_ and/or look into your **Android SDK**

Comment: thank you for your help but my problem have not solve yet . when i changed -Xms512m . .  i can not open my Android Studio .

Comment: updating your **android studio IDE** and **The Android SDK**

Answer (score 5):

My current jvmargs were set to

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m
```

I had to update gradle to 4.10.1 to get rid of this error. Modify your `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file as below

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

Comment: still facing the same issue my currant is this `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Just add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m` in gradle.properties file.