# How to fix Java's heap size problem in android studio

Tags: java, android, gradle

i finished an Android application, when i try to generate the APK file it shows me to set the Java's heap size to 1024m, i did it but im still getting the same error.
 this is a screenshot of the error message and the gradle.proprities file::

[image: Screenshot]

im waiting for your help! thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547100/error-in-build-gradle-in-android-studio

Comment: @PrithviBhola Thanks bro! Method 2 of the best answer worked for me! you saved my day..

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me!

> > METHOD 2 :
>
> Step 1 : Start Android studio and close any open project (File > Close
>   Project).
>
> Step 2 : On Welcome window, Go to Configure > Settings.
>
> Step 3 : Go to Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler
>
> Step 4 : Change Build process heap size (Mbytes) to 512 and Additional
>   build process to VM Options to -Xmx512m. Or any memory allocation in
>   correspondent to your PC
>
> Step 5 : Revalidate/Restart Android Studio.
>   [![enter image description here][1]][1]

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39547461/4450923