# Gradle build fails with Out of Memory: Java heap space error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, out-of-memory, gradle.properties

I am getting gradle build error while running the app. I am using windows 10 with 8GB RAM, Android studio version 4.0.1

> Out of memory: Java heap space. Please assign more memory to Gradle in
> the project's gradle.properties file. For example, the following line,
> in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to
> 1,024 MB: *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m*

Even after following the same steps I am not able to run the app. Could anyone help with a permanent solution for this error???

Here is my gradle.properties file:

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Can you tell me which os you using ? (Windows/Mac...) how many GB of RAM you have ? And share your project gradle.properties please

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547100/android-studio-build-gradle-outofmemoryerror

Answer (score 22):

1. Give more RAM for gradle `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g`
2. If you face the same problem after can run for a few times, open `Task Manager`, `End task` any `Open JDK Platform binary` or `Java(TM) Se Binary` to release RAM, then you can run project again.

If your computer have less than 8GB RAM, set like this in your `gradle.properties` `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M`

Answer (score 8):

I faced the same issue in my `"react": "17.0.2","react-native": "0.66.1"` project 
Goto `project/android/gradlew.properties` 
& uncomment this line 
`# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`

and only change the code before colan(:) 
 `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX` to  
 `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX`

then save and run your build

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a big android project with multiple modules and flavors and had the same problem.

I tried everything from tweaking memory to cleaning project, restarting while invalidating cache, deleting sources and recloning from repo.

I ended up deleting the ".gradle" folder in my user folder and recloning my project.. and it worked. Lost a lot of time on this though.

Answer (score -1):

Adding `android:largeHeap="true"` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` may solve your problem, if you haven't already added. But note that the main issue is your app is consuming too much memory. Consider tracking your app at runtime to find the unusual memory consuming process/objects.

```
<manifest 
     ...
     <application 
         android:largeHeap="true"
         ...

     </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I have already added, it worked once but when I tried to run again then same error

Comment: There can be many possibilities leading to `OutOfMemoryException`. `ListView`s, too many living `Fragment`s, loading high quality images etc. So try to figure out the memory killer objects in your code.

Comment: This for app when u can build, the error message appear when he building the project

Comment: Yes I am not able to run my app then how would I figure out anything?