# I Am Getting A Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android-studio, compiler-errors, out-of-memory

I Am Getting A Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message) While Generating A Signed Android App Bundle (AAB) Of My project.
Here Is The Full Error Message-

***Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError (no error message)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.***

I Tried Running It With --stacktrace And it Is Showing Different Error-
***Out of memory: Java heap space. Configure Gradle memory settings using '-Xmx' JVM option (e.g. '-Xmx2048m'.)
Please fix the project's Gradle settings.***

I Am Not Getting Any Error Message And Searched A Lot To Solve This Problem. Any Help Will Be Appreciated.

Comment: Did you try what your IDE (I assume) suggested you try?  "Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace".  But apart from that, no-one here can hep you debug code that you have not shown us.

Comment: Here's The New Error- Out of memory: Java heap space. Configure Gradle memory settings using '-Xmx' JVM option (e.g. '-Xmx2048m'.)

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.

Comment: Oh, I guess you're not running your code, you're running signing code. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes. When I Run The App On My Device To Test It It Runs Perfectly But When I Am Trying To Generate Signed AAB It Is Showing The Above Mentioned Error

Comment: @Arnav - Question: why are you capitalizing every word?  In English the convention is to capitalize the first word of a sentence, proper names and ... I.

Comment: The Gradle process has filled up its heap. The solution is to do what the error message says. *"Configure Gradle memory settings using '-Xmx' JVM option (e.g. '-Xmx2048m'.) Please fix the project's Gradle settings."*.  You can read about the `-Xmx` option in the Java manual.

Comment: I know, I have a habit of typing Like This. B.t.w if you know the how to solve the error please tell.

Comment: It is a bad habit.  People find it distracting when you write like that.  Counterproductive.

Comment: It helped me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Build gradle OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547100/android-studio-build-gradle-outofmemoryerror)

Answer (score 11):

Go to `Settings > Appearance behavior > System settings > Memory settings` and set everything to its maximum value.

[image]