# OutOfMemory exception occurred on Flutter build

Tags: flutter

Can't do `flutter run`. `flutter doctor` is ok. What to do? I'm using Flutter version 2.8.1.

```
Failed to execute org.gradle.cache.internal.AsyncCacheAccessDecoratedCache$2@7c56f8f1.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer located here:
[Android Studio Build gradle OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39547100/android-studio-build-gradle-outofmemoryerror)

Step 1 : Start Android studio and close any open project (File > Close Project).

Step 2 : On Welcome window, Go to Configure > Settings.

Step 3 : Go to Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler

Step 4 : Change Build process heap size (Mbytes) to 512 and Additional build process to VM Options to -Xmx512m. Or any memory allocation in correspondent to your PC

Step 5 : Revalidate/Restart Android Studio.

Or you can also try commenting out this block in build.gradle

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not helps.I can see after adding this parameters:  [  +95 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
[+30000 ms] > Task :app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug
[+281900 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +2 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Java heap space