# Execution failed for task ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug'. (Android Studio can't execute)

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't run or execute my code. I already followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022765/failed-to-sync-gradle-project).

It still won't work. My error message

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug'.
>   Java heap space
>   ties file.
>   For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
>   *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m*
>   [Read Gradle's configuration guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)
> [Read about Java's heap size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

I tried turning off the instant run and there's a new error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>   Java heap space
>   ect's gradle.properties file.
>   For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
>   *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m*
>   [Read Gradle's configuration guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)
> [Read about Java's heap size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

EDIT: I found the reason why. It's because i added a code that'll unzip a 500 mb file and will transfer into the internal storage. It might be because it has a lot of files. The zipfile has 80,000+ files.

Comment: What is RAM of your machine?

Comment: 4gb RAM. It was working but i reinstalled it because it was taking too long to execute when i installed instant run. But after reinstalling, this produces an error.

Comment: Try this -> https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html

Comment: tried it still not working. I'll try reinstalling again maybe it will work this time.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason of this error could be mismatch of JDK versions.Try to check your system Java Version with Your Studio's version.

```
java -version
```

should be similar to Android Studio `File > Project Structure > JDK Location` version.

Comment: how do i validate the version to my android studio? @Anurag Pandit

Comment: In your terminal give above command "java -version" it will show you system's java version for example " java version "1.8.0_74" " and in your Project Settings below SDK location find JDK " it should be equivalent to system's version, example "java-8-oracle" .

Answer (score 0):

Today after java update , i have this issue Execution failed for task ':**app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug**', when i run "gradlew build --stacktrace"  console show me that in my java path C:\Program Files\Java**jre1.8.0_121**\lib , java can`t find **tools.jar**, perhaps after update java on my pc for some reason deleted this file, but fortunately i have another version of java on my pc C:\Program Files\Java**jdk1.8.0**_101 and i copy-past tools.jar from this location to my jre1.8.0 . Perhaps some one help this.