# How to automatically set gradle.properties

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, default

Normally when I create a new project, I get this error at first when Android is trying to build the Gradle:

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough space for object heap.
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
<em>org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m</em>
<a href="http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html">Read Gradle's configuration guide</a><br><a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html">Read about Java's heap size</a>
```

That's pretty easy to fix; you just go to gradle.properties in your app module, then add this in the last line:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m
```

Ok Seems All Good. You may be asking then, what's the problem? Well my problem is I have to do that every time! Every time I have to open my notepad I saved the above sentence then copy paste. This is getting kind of ridiculous. Is there any way I can default the gradle.properties to contain the above line every time I create a new project? Thanks for helping!

**BTW**: This is Android Studio

Comment: Do you have a 64 bit machine and Android studio is set to a 32 bit jdk?

Comment: This is Android Studio @cricket_007 and Devrim

Comment: Nvm i have a 64BIT Machine. And Idk how to set Android Studio to 32BIT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Java Heap size in Android Studio 1.3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964072/error-java-heap-size-in-android-studio-1-3-1)

Comment: if you are on a 64 bit machine try to use 64 bit jdk at your android studio. http://askubuntu.com/questions/467870/how-to-set-the-jdk-for-android-studio . that must be your problem I guess

Comment: Downloading the whole thing again @DevrimTuncer . It was horrificly tiresome to download the whole studio the first time. I dont think im going to do it again. And Cricket, We both know the question you pointed to is not the same.

Comment: And @cricket_007 , We both know the question you pointed to is not the same

Comment: Really? Error looks the same to me. Regardless, the answer is what you want to look at.

Comment: Lol @cricket_007 ... Im not confused on why it gives me that heap error. Im trying to make it default so i dont have to constantly write the code above in my gradle.properties like i already explained in my question

Comment: I understand that. The answer provided in that other post tells you exactly what you need to do to make it default.

Comment: Do not download anything :) Could you please check that you are using JDK (java) 64 it at your android studio?

Comment: Lol! I have both 32 bit and 64 bit andrio studio!! @DevrimTuncer

Comment: I'm talking about JDK (Java Development Kit) not the android studio. Just check that please, if you are on a 64 bit machine, you should use 64 bit JDK. If you are on a 64 bit machine, android studio is going to arrange the heap size for 64 bit. But if you had set the JDK 32 bit for the android studio (I am talking about the JDK again) that would fail with heap size. Go "File -> Project Structure JDK Location". If it is referred to 64 bit JDK, I have nothing to suggest you. I just guess that it is referred to 32 bir JDK. (btw don't lol too much if you want an answer to your question)

Comment: I dont understand @DevrimTuncer ...