# android studio application cannot be run in windows 7 machine

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

In my Android studio I got following error when run the application.

```
Error:Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error:Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Error:Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error:Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Error:Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
Error:The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error:Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
Error:The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
:dmart-android:transformClassesWithDexForDev FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':dmart-android:transformClassesWithDexForDev'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have 32 bit windows 7 machine and could not able to run.
Please let me know how to clear the errors.

Comment: possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964072/error-java-heap-size-in-android-studio-1-3-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed Windows 7 with 32 bit and used 8 Ram so the system only used 4GB only I have installed 64 bit OS. Now its working.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the first you will have to reconfigure your AVD (Android Virtual Device) to a smaller heap size, This can be done by opening the AVD Manager via Tools>Android>AVD manger

You should see your virtual device in the window that opens. choose the green pencil icon at the right of the window to edit the device configuration.

The Heap, Storage and RAM setting of the device are found under the advance setting tap. you can modify them to suit your computer.

Please note that the performance of you ADV depends on the hardware of the computer you are using ( this means you cannot run you AVD on 4Gb RAM when your computer does not have more than 4 Gb RAM)