# Android studio - Java heap space

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Suddenly my app cant run and pop this error out...any idea for this error ? tried so hard still can't solve...

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageInstantRunResourcesDebug'.
```

> Java heap space
>   ties file.
>   For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
>   *org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m*
>   [Read Gradle's configuration guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)
> [Read about Java's heap size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)

Comment: Upload your gradle-wrapper.properties file

Comment: Has it run out of heap space? Try adding `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m` to your `gradle.properties`-file.

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox add insert android studio or my folder? edit with notepad?

Comment: @HarshitSeksaria Unable to upload txt file though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Java Heap size in Android Studio 1.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964072/error-java-heap-size-in-android-studio-1-3-1)

Comment: @Thomas.Chan Try opening it with a notepad and add that to a new line.

Comment: @Thomas.Chan, copy the code for that file and then paste it. either in comment or edit your question

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox Here it is what inside the gradle-wrapper.properties file               
#Mon Dec 28 10:00:20 PST 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip

Comment: @Thomas.Chan Okay. Just add `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m` in a new line now.

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox and i added org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m in my gradle.properties inside android studio it show unused property.

Comment: @Thomas.Chan Ignore the warning. Try whatever you wanted to try in the beginning.

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox Yeah..i searched alot of method but doesn't work for me...

Comment: @ImpulseTheFox After add in still the same error.

Comment: @Thomas.Chan Then I don't know what do to either, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

there will be **gradle.properties** file in project directory.

> /path/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectNameFolder/gradle.properties

add this line to allocate 1.5 GB heap to android studio.

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m